# Computer runs out of space when indexing database on external disk

Tags: windows, sqlite

I have an SQLite database of about 80 GB on an external harddrive. I want to index some of the columns there, but when I do the operation fails after some time, with this error: `sqlite3.OperationalError: database or disk is full`

The external harddrive has 386 gb free space, while my local windows disk has 63 gb free space, so I suspect that SQLite use some temp storage on my local disc. Is my only option to reduce space on my local computer? Can I safely set operations on this database to use tmp storage on the external harddrive?

Disclaimer: I know it isn't best practice to use an external harddrive, however this isn't for production data, and I have several copies of this database.